# Not all Nintex workflow steps occuring

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow

I have a "visit notification" workflow which is triggered when "visit required?"=Yes and "Sales email sent? "=No.

The workflow steps are

- Send email
- Change "visit date" to "Date to be confirmed"
- Change  "visit email sent? "=Yes (to ensure the workflow does not
  trigger more than once.)

The workflow triggered at the correct time and completed with no errors.

- Send email --> email was sent
- "visit date" --> was changed to "Date to be confirmed"
- "visit email sent? " --> stayed at No

Consequently when the item was edited again the workflow was triggered a second time.

Why would one of the update field steps work correctly and one not?

Comment: Are they subsequent actions, parallel or in any other type of logic flow? You could also try throwing a commit action after first item for good measure.

Comment: Subsequent actions no other logic. What is a commit action? If you mean "Commit pending changes" I would expect that to trigger the email after each step which is not what I need

Comment: Ohh yes "Commit pending changes". Updates to list items are not done instantly, they are batched and might sometime introduce unexpected behavior. Not good performance wise to have it anywhere but while debugging you can eliminate that as a potential issue.